# My modal keep on reloading when password and password two did not match

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this php code. If password and password2 did not match, there will be a pop up saying that your password did not match, and if it is match, data will go directly to the database. My only problem here is that, after clicking ok on the popup window, the page will redirect to blank page. I dont want it to reload or i just want to stay in the modal of registration form.

```
<?php
include ("RegisteredUsers.php");

$tbl_name="register";

if(isset($_POST['RegButton'])) 
{
$RegUser=$_POST['RegUser'];
$RegMail=$_POST['RegMail'];
$RegPass=$_POST['RegPass'];
$CRegPass=$_POST['CRegPass'];

if($_POST['RegPass'] != $_POST['CRegPass'])
{

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>;
    alert('Password did not match!')
    CRegPass.focus();
    </script>";
    exit();

}
else
{   
    $sql="INSERT INTO `register`( `Username`, `Eadd`, `pass`, `cpass`) 
 VALUES ('$RegUser','$RegMail','$RegPass','$CRegPass')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql)or die("Insert Error: ".mysql_error());

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>;
    alert('Registration Complete!')
    location.replace('Homepage.php')
    </script>";

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Where is `CRegPass` defined? `CRegPass.focus();`

Comment: Java != javascript. Things you should fix 1. Hash the password 2. Updat the driver (mysqli or PDO) and parameterize the query 3. Dont store the confirm password (it will always be the same) . I'd also use PHP `header` rather than JS `location.replace`, you can append a `GET` parameter to the URL and display it on the redirected page.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using ajax for this type of action. If you are using traditional form submission system, So you will not achieve desire output.
Because when u click submit button then it is going to it's action page.
For this reason u are getting blank page.